# Making a Hibernate @ManyToOne association a Scala Option type

Tags: hibernate, scala

Anyone has an example of using a wrapper-object, like Scala's Option, for @ManyToOne associations in Hibernate?

Thanks.

Edited:
Thanks for suggestions. After further thought I've setteled on using private variables and exposing them having scala getters/setters which return Option[MyType]. Like this:

```
class EmailFolder(__parent: Option[EmailFolder] = None) {

    //.... default constructor etc...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private[this] var _parent: EmailFolder = __parent.orNull
    def parent = Option(_parent)
    def parent_=(newVal:Option[EmailFolder]) = _parent = newVal.orNull
}
```

This works and I no longer have to work with nulls in my application.

--
Andreas

Comment: I'm not a Scala guy, but looking at Option it seems you could be trying to get one of two things: the null vs not-null sense (None vs Some) or the one of many types thing.  Which is it?

Comment: The point is that the the @ManyToOne relation is optional and I don't want to pass null-values for that association around but want to use an Option to either pass Some(MyObject) or None for whether the DB-value is null or not, using a custom Hibernate UserType to do the conversion to/from Option (Some or None).

Comment: Do the classes that you're wrapping have a common base class, other than Object or some other Java built-in class?

Comment: I want to wrap arbitrary objects which I might use as a @ManyToOne association in an Option so that I never pass <null>-values around.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought here was to make a class, call it `Option`, mark it as an `@Embeddable`, then giving it a reference to a common base class for the set of objects you might want to refer to (call it `DomainObject`).

Doing this though means you might need to give up a couple of things:

1. "...arbitrary objects..."  You can't have a `@ManyToOne` reference to a fully arbitrary class in Hibernate.  It needs to be to a specific Hibernate Entity or Entity hierarchy: ie, `DomainObject`, otherwise Hibernate has no way of knowing what tables to query at fetch time.
2. "...null values..." Hibernate does some special stuff for Elements (aka `@Embeddable`).  In particular, if the Element only contains null references, then the reference to the Element itself is null.

So you could take that approach, but you'd end up with a base class that you possibly don't want, and some extraneous field in the Element class simply to make sure the Element itself isn't null.  Bit of a pain.

Instead, I'd recommend keeping your Option class out of Hibernate entirely.  In Entities that have Options, use the [access type setting](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e1955) so that Hibernate accesses the member via the field, not methods.  Implement the getter like so:

```
...
@ManyToOne
private MyObjectType myObjectReference;

public Option<MyObjectType> getMyObject() {
    return new Option(this.myObjectReference);
}
...
```

Another options is to not do field-level access, but instead have inner, private getter/setter for Hibernate to deal with the field, and public getter/setters that wrap it in an Option for the rest of your application to see.

Only con here is that the getter has to do some real work as opposed to being a simple POJO method.  But I think it's worth it not to twist Hibernate in knots.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also make `myObjectReference` `private`.

Comment: @ericacm fair enough.  Added the field to be clear it's private.